# In python: how to see the attributes of a 'property object'？

Tags: python

I created a property object like this:

```
a=property()
```

but when I ran

```
list(a.__dict__)
```

it raised an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

So,my question is how to see the attributes of a 'property object'？don't use dir(),because I don't want to see the attributes that inherit from its super class.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? On my Python 3.5.2 build I see `AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__dict__'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property object has no attributes because as you stated, it doesn't have a `__dict__`. Observe:

```
>>> list(m for m in dir(a) if m not in dir(type(a)))
[]
```

If you are wanting to access the getter/setter/deleter, do it this way:

```
a.getter
a.setter
a.deleter
```